# Conflicting type while trying to compile a lib with msys2

Tags: c, windows, compiler-errors, msys2

I'm trying to compile [wcslib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnuastro/manual/html_node/WCSLIB.html) under Windows/msys2.
While this library compiles with no isue on GNU/Linux and MacOS I'm facing to an annyoing issue with msys2:

```
wcs.h:1965:5: error: conflicting types for 'wcsset'
1965 | int wcsset(struct wcsprm *wcs);
| ^~~~~~
In file included from wcs.c:30:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:179:20: note: previous declaration of 'wcsset' was here
179 | wchar_t *__cdecl wcsset(wchar_t *_Str,wchar_t _Val) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
| ^~~~~~
wcs.c:2185:5: error: conflicting types for 'wcsset'
2185 | int wcsset(struct wcsprm *wcs)
| ^~~~~~
In file included from wcs.c:30:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:179:20: note: previous declaration of 'wcsset' was here
179 | wchar_t *__cdecl wcsset(wchar_t *_Str,wchar_t _Val) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
| ^~~~~~
make[3]: *** [GNUmakefile:135: libwcs-7.3.1.a(wcs.o)] Error 1
　
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcsbth.c
In file included from wcsbth.l:121: 
wcs.h:1965:5: error: conflicting types for 'wcsset'  
1965 | int wcsset(struct wcsprm *wcs);
| ^~~~~~
In file included from wcsbth.c:231:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:179:20: note: previous declaration of 'wcsset' was here
179 | wchar_t *__cdecl wcsset(wchar_t *_Str,wchar_t _Val) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
| ^~~~~~
make[3]: *** [GNUmakefile:135: libwcs-7.3.1.a(wcsbth.o)] Error 1

gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcserr.c

gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcsfix.c
In file included from wcsfix.c:38:
wcs.h:1965:5: error: conflicting types for 'wcsset'
1965 | int wcsset(struct wcsprm *wcs);
| ^~~~~~
In file included from wcsfix.c:30:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:179:20: note: previous declaration of 'wcsset' was here
179 | wchar_t *__cdecl wcsset(wchar_t *_Str,wchar_t _Val) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
| ^~~~~~
make[3]: *** [GNUmakefile:135: libwcs-7.3.1.a(wcsfix.o)] Error 1

gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcshdr.c
In file included from wcshdr.h:1276,
from wcshdr.c:36:
wcs.h:1965:5: error: conflicting types for 'wcsset'
1965 | int wcsset(struct wcsprm *wcs);
| ^~~~~~
In file included from wcshdr.c:31:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:179:20: note: previous declaration of 'wcsset' was here
179 | wchar_t *__cdecl wcsset(wchar_t *_Str,wchar_t _Val) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
| ^~~~~~
make[3]: *** [GNUmakefile:135: libwcs-7.3.1.a(wcshdr.o)] Error 1

gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcspih.c
In file included from wcspih.l:123:
wcs.h:1965:5: error: conflicting types for 'wcsset'
1965 | int wcsset(struct wcsprm *wcs);
| ^~~~~~
In file included from wcspih.c:231:
C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/string.h:179:20: note: previous declaration of 'wcsset' was here
179 | wchar_t *__cdecl wcsset(wchar_t *_Str,wchar_t _Val) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005;
| ^~~~~~
make[3]: *** [GNUmakefile:135: libwcs-7.3.1.a(wcspih.o)] Error 1

gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcsprintf.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcstrig.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcsulex.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcsunits.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcsutil.c
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -c wcsutrn.c
make[3]: Target 'libwcs-7.3.1.a' not remade because of errors.
make[2]: *** [GNUmakefile:258: lib] Error 2
make[2]: Target 'build' not remade because of errors.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/siril/wcslib-7.3.1/C'
Mon 2020/12/07 09:23:14 +0100, executing on
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/siril/wcslib-7.3.1/utils'
cd .. && ./config.status
config.status: creating makedefs
config.status: creating wcslib.pc
config.status: creating wcsconfig.h
config.status: creating wcsconfig_f77.h
config.status: wcsconfig_f77.h is unchanged
config.status: creating wcsconfig_tests.h
config.status: wcsconfig_tests.h is unchanged
config.status: creating wcsconfig_utils.h
　
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I../C -g -O2 -c -o fitshdr.o fitshdr.c   
gcc -o fitshdr fitshdr.o -lm -pthread -lcurl -lm  
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/siril/wcslib-7.3.1/utils'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/siril/wcslib-7.3.1'
```

Of course, changing the name of lib function is not an option (at least not my option). Does someone knows a good option to get out of it. For example a way to remove the symbols or ... something else.

Comment: Your error output seems messier than it should be.  I suspect you were running multiple Make jobs at the same time, so that is why we see errors from a bunch of jobs instead of just one.  Next time, you might try building your software with `make -j1` to explicitly tell Make not to run multiple jobs.

Comment: I run it on a VM. with make -j1

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at the `string.h` file mentioned in your error message.  It looks like you can define a proprocessor macro `NO_OLDNAMES` to tell the header file not to produce a prototype for `wcsset`.

You still need to watch out for trouble at link time, but this might be good enough.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try it